Can I modify the Azure Devops Pr Page Comment Box
I am trying to add a button to pr page comment box on azure devops. However I couldn’t find the connection point to do so in the documentation.
I tried to add it to pr-review page but i couldnt here is my manifest.json:
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "id": "pr-comment-ai-helper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "PR Comment AI Helper",
  "publisher": "tacocat",
  "description": "Adds an AI button to PR comment boxes.",
  "targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
  ],
  "categories": ["Azure Repos"],
  "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "pr-comment-button",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.page-contribution",
      "description": "AI Comment Helper",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-code-web.pull-request-review-route"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "uri": "./dist/bundle.js"
      }
    }
  ],
  "debug": {
    "uri": "http://localhost:3000/bundle.js"
  }
}

